# How to obtain values from a matrix using stored numbers as indexes in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

am really new at R and I can't find the way of subsetting matrix rows given a list of indexes.

I have a dataframe called 'demo' with 855 rows and 3 columns that looks like this:

```
 ##         Subject  AGE DX
 ## 1 011_S_0002_bl 74.3  0
 ## 2 011_S_0003_bl 81.3  1
 ## 3 011_S_0005_bl 73.7  0
 ## 4 022_S_0007_bl 75.4  1
 ## 5 011_S_0008_bl 84.5  0
 ## 6 011_S_0010_bl 73.9  1
```

From this, I want to extract the indexes for all the rows that match DX == 1. So I do:

```
rownames(demo[demo$DX == 1,])
```

Which returns:

```
 ##   [1] "2"   "4"   "6"   "14"  "20"  "31"  "33"  "34"  "36"  "39"  "40"  "41"
 ##  [13] "46"  "47"  "53"  "54"  "55"  "58"  "64"  "67"  "69"  "70"  "72"  "81"
 ##  [25] "84"  "87"  "88"  "92"  "96"  "98"  "100" "101" "106" "108" "109" "112"
....
```

Now I have a matrix called T_hat with 855 rows and 1 column that looks like this:

```
##           [,1]
## [1,]  5.812925
## [2,] 10.477721
## [3,]  1.519726
## [4,] -0.221328
## [5,]  1.784920
```

What I want is to use the numbers in 'al' to subset the values with the corresponding numbers in the indexes and to get something like this:

```
##           [,1]
## [2,] 10.477721
## [4,] -0.221328
```

...and so on.

I've tried all these options:

```
T_hat_a <- T_hat[rownames(demo[demo$DX == 1,]),1]
T_hat_b <- T_hat[is.numeric(rownames(demo[demo$DX == 1,])),1]
T_hat_c <- T_hat[rownames(T_hat) %in% rownames(demo[demo$DX == 1,]),1]
T_hat_d <- T_hat[rownames(T_hat) %in% is.numeric(rownames(demo[demo$DX == 1,])),1]
```

But none returns what I expect.

> T_hat_a = ERROR "no 'dimnames' attributes for array

> T_hat_b = numeric(0)

> T_hat_c = numeric(0)

> T_hat_d = numeric(0)

I've also tried to convert my matrix to a df, but only the T_hat_a option returns a result, but it is not at all as desired, since it returns different values...

Comment: Try this (assuming that your logic in creating `al_ind` was correct)  : `alzheimer <- P[rownames(volumes[is.element(volumes$Subject, al),]),1]`  (you should not need to coerce the rownames to numeric and you definitely do not need a list built with `append`. That would horribly inefficient. It's practically an example of the most inefficient way to do this.. Learn to use R indexing.

Comment: If you provide a working example with some toy data, it'd be easier to show you a simpler way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you both! So sorry for my bad explanation, I've edited my question with data examples so it's easier to understand my problem.